# Display json data with angular 7

Tags: json, angular7

I want to display json data on screen with Angular 7.  I have an error.

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

In my service;

```
getData(): Observable <any> {
        return this.http.get(this.myUrl);
    }
```

In my component;

```
public data: []= null;

    ngOnInit() {
          this.myService.getData().subscribe((d) => this.data = d);
      }
```

In my html;

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor = "let people of data">
    <td> {{ people.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

My json;

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "number": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "name": "arya"
        },
        {
            "number": [
                1,
                1
            ],
            "name": "arya2"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I display these data, which in json, on screen with html?

Comment: You data is an object, not an array.

Comment: Yes, how can I read this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your variable `data` with an empty array.

```
public data: [] = [];
```

and assign `d.person` to `data` variable.

`this.myService.getData().subscribe((d) => this.data = d.people);`

Comment: Ok. Now I have a different error.                                                                   
Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: Thank you so much for your helps. Your answer was very helpful.

Comment: I have one more question @michaelitoh. Assume that, json data is constantly changing. And I want display these data on screen updately. For example, **arya: 0 arya2: 1** How can I display?

Comment: Please create another question.